# Google OR-Tools - Routing - Penalties - Adding Different Penalty to Different Location (Python)

Tags: python, optimization

I am using Google's OR-Tools for route optimisation. References can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties).

I am performing an optimisation where certain pick-up locations are dropped based on a penalty at each location. The documentation gives an example and states: *"In this context, a disjunction is simply a variable that the solver uses to decide whether to include a given location in the solution. In this example, the method adds the same penalty to each location, but in general you can add different penalties to different locations."*, and provides the following chunk of code as an example of adding a **constant** penalty to each location:

```
penalty = 1000
for node in range(1, len(data['distance_matrix'])):
    routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], penalty)
```

where `data` is a `dict` containing a `n x n` distance matrix (`distance_matrix`). *(This code runs and returns a sensible outcome).*

Now, I would like to vary the penalty at each location, and I've used the following code to do so:

```
for node in range(1, len(data['distance_matrix'])):
    routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], data['penalty'][manager.NodeToIndex(node)])
```

where `penalty` is an array of length `n` containing penalties for each location. (In these examples, the depot is assumed to be at the first location and is penalty-free; `range` starts at 1).

When I run my code, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'RoutingModel_AddDisjunction'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
operations_research::RoutingModel::AddDisjunction(std::vector< int64 > const &,int64,int64)
operations_research::RoutingModel::AddDisjunction(std::vector< int64 > const &,int64)
operations_research::RoutingModel::AddDisjunction(std::vector< int64 > const &)
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How do I go about adding different penalties to different locations? Could someone please translate the C/C++ into Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, it looks like `data['penalty'][manager.NodeToIndex(node)]` is not an integer, probably a float, and therefore it doesn't match the function signature, as the error message suggests. Try converting it to an integer.

Comment: You are partially correct. I tried using `penalty = 1000.0` in the first example and the process threw the error again. However, when I convert the variable penalties to `int` the error is not resolved.

Comment: @bradS, that sounds strange, do you have small example that reproduces the error that you can share?

Comment: you are correct - wrapping the problematic bit in an `int()` solved the issue - thank you!

Comment: If determining whether to add a stop surcharge for a node visit, is using `routing.AddDisjunction()` the way to go? Or something like a dimension dependent arc cost instead (i.e. `AddDimensionDependentDimensionWithVehicleCapacity()')? I can't find a way to pass logic into creating the penalties that takes into account where in the route I am so I can decide whether to add a surcharge cost or not. Anyone have luck with adding penalties based on the route features itself?